# How to create child component in array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, typescript-generics

I have a recoder component in angular using typescript:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';

interface Record {
  startTime: Date;
  endTime: Date;
  duration: number;
  isDone: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-record',
  templateUrl: './record.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./record.component.css']
})
export class RecordComponent {
  @Input() buttonType: string;
  @Input() buttonName: string;
  @Output() valueEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
    this.buttonType = 'start';
    this.buttonName = 'start';
  }

  private startTime: Date | null = null;
  private timer: any;
  public count = 0;
  public disabled = false;

  onClick(): void {
    if(!this.startTime) {
      this.startTimer();
    } else {
      this.stopTimer();
      this.buttonType='done';
      this.buttonName='done';
    }
  }

  startTimer(): void {
    this.buttonType='stop';
    this.buttonName='stop';
    this.startTime = new Date();
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.count ++;
    }, 1000);
  }

  stopTimer(): void {
    const endTime = new Date();
    const duration = endTime.getTime() - this.startTime!.getTime();
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    this.startTime = null;
    this.count = Math.floor(duration/1000);
    this.disabled = true;
    const value = 'TIMER_STOPPED';
    this.valueEmitter.emit(value);
  }
}
```

This is my record component and when stopTimer triggered, I want to add one more child component below it. FOr this, I am trying to send a value = 'TIMER_STOPPED'; to parent component. Here is my parent component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RecordComponent } from '../record/record.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracker',
  templateUrl: './tracker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css'],
})
export class TrackerComponent {
  public records:[] = [];

  addRecord(): void {
    const _record = new RecordComponent();
    _record.id++;
    _record.length = 1200;
    this.records.push(_record);
  }

  handleValue(value: string) {
    if (value === 'TIMER_STOPPED') {
      this.addRecord();
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, if the `value === 'TIMER_STOPPED'` which means timer is stopped, I want to add another component at the top of the array (so old one should be always at the top ) but I am really new in angular. Even the timer is stopped, the new component cannot be added. Is this the good approach for this kind of challenges?

Thanks for helping.

I achieved sending the value to parent component, but in parent component, I couldn't add another child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add a component to the array. Use data instead.

*Example*

```
class Record {
  public name: string;
  public length: number;
}
```

Then you can loop it witn `*ngFor` in your parent.

**HTML Parent**

```
<div *ngIf="!records || records.length === 0">NO RECORDS</div>

<record-component *ngFor="let record of records" [buttonName]="record.name" [length]="record.length"></record-component>
```

To add new inside your parent use this:

```
addRecord() {
  const _record = new Record();
  _record.name = "Test";
  _record.length = 1200;
  this.records.push(_record);
  
  // Wanna add it on top?
  // this.records.splice(0, 0, _record);
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jyw34?file=src/main.ts) is a Stackblitz example.

All other will Angular do for you.

Comment: I edited my parent component like you recommended and you can see updated but I am getting an error like: error TS2345: Argument of type 'RecordComponent' is not assignable to parameter 
of type 'never'.

16     this.records.push(_record);

Comment: Yes. Because - I wrote it in my answer - do "not" add Components in your array. Use objects and let Angular create the component in the html part.

Comment: One more thing, since he object is emptym curently I see nothing. How can I mount in angular as soon as the page is rendered to show initials

Comment: With `*ngIf` you can show/hide things. So if record is empty, show "NO RECORDS". I have updated my answer and added a Stackblitz example!